# How to plug a twisted electrical wire

Tags: home, safety, electricity

In the part of the world where I live, some workers carry multiple pieces of long wires in case the power source is far away, so they can connect various wires and reach the plug.

Since most of these wires need to be connected to each other, there is no plug at the end of the wire.  Is there any safe life hack that can ensure both that this is safe and the wire is plugged properly so it does not fall off easily.

I don't do this, but I have seen many workers do this, but to hang on to the plug they insert wooden pieces (something of the size of two matchsticks into the plug together) which reasonably does the job of keeping it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break this into two parts.

## Safe Practice

---

Safe? Doing that is only a bit more safe than walking with traffic in the middle of a busy freeway. That is a *terrible* idea. You can get electrocuted at any point in the line. You can electrocute other people in the line. You can electrocute animals. You can electrocute the entire world. Don't do that.

## Doesn't fall off easy

---

Okay. If you stick a piece of wire in an outlet, what's holding it in?  It's just a wire. And, by how often my USB cord (with a latch) slides out of my phone, I can assure you that it will fall out.

## Ways to do what you want

---

Luckily, there are a few ways to do what you want. I've given them each a "safety score" (ϟ) between 1 and 5 as well as a "lifehack score" (★) between 1 and 5. 5 is the highest in both cases.

- ***Electrical Tape*** (ϟϟϟϟ, ★★★★★☆)

For this lifehack, you're going to want to take all of the wires and lay them out, Tape up the wires to each other. Then, carefully jam two ends into the wall. Make sure the other two ends aren't touching, though.

- ***Electrical Tape + Outlet End + Receptacle*** (ϟϟϟ, ★★★★☆)

For  the Junction Box trick, you're going to want an outlet end, a receptacle, and a bunch of electrical tape.  (Solder is optional and makes it more reliable).

> 1. Get an outlet end from a broken appliance. Trim the wires so you have some leeway.
> 2. Attach your outlet end to the wires. (Solder them.)
> 3. Tape it up.
> 4. Follow Electrical Tape rules.
> 5. Attach the other end of the wires to a receptacle.
> 6. Put that receptacle in a junction box.
> 7. Enjoy your homemade extension cord!

- ***Electrical Tape + Bought Outlet End + Receptacle*** (ϟϟ, ★★☆☆☆)

> 1. Get an outlet end from your local hardware store. They have screws in them.
> 2. Follow above steps.
> 3. Enjoy your homemade extension cord.

- ***Extension Cord*** (ϟ, ☆☆☆☆☆)

Go to the local store and buy an extension cord.

Comment: For your information this is not a made up question, every time I meet someone using this method I want to credibly inform them of easy alternatives and no extension cord or safe plug is not a practical solution to them.  Your answer provides some great options though

Comment: I think you mean 'danger score' instead of 'safety score' - more ϟ's is less safe, right?

Answer (score 6):

There may be inexpensive, and mayn times reusable screw terminals available in the region you live:

[image]  
<sup>[Image source Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Leuchterklemme_75dpi.jpg)</sup>

This will ensure a firm connection of electrical wires needing only a screw driver (and a tool to remove insulation at the ends) to fit them.

A drawback of these screw terminals is their very limited safety. Conductive parts may be exposed, and touching them will cause a shock of course. In addition those contacts are not suitable for moist or wet environments.

To increase safety we can wrap them in insulating tape or (preferrably) put them in a [box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocbox).

Answer (score 1):

Connect the ends together by twisting, then wrap the junction in a plastic bag (like a ziploc freezer bag) and attach the end of the bag to the cable with electrical tape.

This uses far less electrical tape (makes taking it apart easier), while protecting the cord from a short, except in the case of water.

To keep the wires from falling out of the outlet, this is a safety issue, and should be avoided if at all possible. Try taping the cord to the wall near the outlet, so that if the cord gets pulled, the stress is put on the tape/wall, rather than trying to connect directly with the outlet.